# How to get the URL/source of an image that has been attached and uploaded to MongoDB?(wysiwyg)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, markdown, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am creating a blog-post website via markdown(with NEXTJS and Typescript) and the issue that I am currently facing is in the panel where the post is being created when image from /url or source from local machine/ is being submitted.

The panel does preview the image in the textarea element but once submitted to my MongoDB collection, what I get is an empty space in the place of the image. The packages that I am using are - react-draft-wysiwyg - which is the package that enables me to create content and providing me with the creation panel in markdown version and also the package that helps attach images - and for rendering I am using react-markdown - so I can be able to convert markdown to html - used along with remark-gfm as a plugin for the render.

So the question is how can I can also attach/get the url/source of the given image in markdown to my database collection while using react-draft-wysiwyg as apparently they doesn't respond much in their Github(https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg/issues/1307)

Here is the my code for the creation panel of the blogpost

```
                <Editor
                  wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
                  editorClassName="demo-editor"
                  contentState={contentState}
                  onEditorStateChange={(editorState) => {
                    setEditorState(editorState);
                  }}
                  toolbar={{
                    image: {
                      previewImage: true,
                      urlEnabled: true,
                      uploadEnabled: true,
                      uploadCallback: () => {
                        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                          resolve({
                            data: { link: convertedData.entityMap[0].data.src },
                          });
                        });
                      },
                    },
                  }}
                />
                <textarea
                  disabled
                  hidden
                  onChange={(e) => console.log(contentTextArea)}
                  value={
                    editorState &&
                    draftToMarkdown(
                      convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()),
                      {
                        entityItems: {
                          image: {
                            open: function (entity) {
                              console.log(entity);
                              return 'open';
                            },
                            close: function (entity) {
                              // @ts-ignore
                              console.log(entity);
                              return 'close';
                            },
                          },
                        },
                      }
                    )
                  }
                />
              </div>
            </div>
```

And that's how I am trying to render it

```
{result.map(
                  (post: any, index: React.Key | null | undefined) => {
                    return (
                      <>
                        <h4 key={index} className="text-2xl text-center pt-20">
                          {post.title}
                        </h4>
                        <ReactMarkdown
                          remarkPlugins={[gfm]}
                          className="text-left px-4"
                        >
                          {post.body}
                        </ReactMarkdown>
                      </>
                    );
                  }
                )}
```

This is also what is submitted to my collection in Mongo while trooubleshooting [image: mongodb image upload empty space]

Hopefully I have managed to explain properly the trouble I'm facing,thank You in advance for the shared time and wisdom!